Compare the current value with ALL the previous value(s)
Please check below as a concrete example.
For each id, there are several time intervals. I want to count the number of overlapping intervals, which is defined as the start_time of the current interval < the end_time of ALL the previous intervals.
For example, for id=1,
     3.5<4 (the previous end_time)
     3.8<4, 3.8<4.5
     3.9<4, 3.9<4.5, 3.9<4.8

There are 6 overlapping intervals, while for id=2, since 4.5 > 4, the number of overlapping intervals is ZERO.
id    start_time   end_time
1        3           4
1       3.5         4.5
1       3.8         4.8
1       3.9          5
2       2            4
2       4.5          5
...


I was planning to use LAG() function in MySQL, however, I realized I only could compare the current row with the previous X rows using the offset argument. Is there any good solution to solve this problem in MySQL? Thank you.

You may be able to do this with a self join, but it's going to produce x^2 records.  How large is the table?  Are you using a programming language?

Imagint that for id=3 you have the next intervals: (1,3), (2,4), (5,7), (6,8). There are 2 overlapped intervals pairs which forms 2 non-overlapped groups. Does the output 2 for such data is one you need in?

@TimRoberts I am using MySQL, and the table has 10000 ids.

@Akina, in your example, there should be 2 overlapping intervals since 2<3 and 6<7, and thus, yes, 2 is what I need. Thank you.

Count/merge overlapping intervals is pretty common problem with a simple windoe function solution. What is the expected result for the sample data?

Intervals (1,2) and (2,3) is overlapped?

@ValNik No, since the end time of the 1st interval is not bigger than the start time of the 2nd interval.

@SalmanArshad The expected result is the id and the number of their overlapping shifts. Thank you.

@sophia then it would be a simple count overlapping intervals problems and one of the answers below solves it efficiently

Possible algorithm. Combine starts and ends to one rowset, and add a weight, +1 for starts and -1 for ends. Then calculate cumulative sums for these weights. The amount of rows with cumulative sum of zero is the output which you need in.
Take a look at this assignment from the following perspective. Imagine a room. A person enters this room at the start_time and leaves the room at the end_time. During overlapping time intervals, there are several people in the room, one or more. The room is empty between the overlapping ranges.
WITH 
cte1 (id, timepoint, weight) AS (
  SELECT id, start_time, 1 FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, end_time, -1 FROM test
  ),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT id, timepoint, SUM(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timepoint) cumsum
  FROM cte1
  )
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cumsum = 0 THEN timepoint END) amount
FROM cte2
GROUP BY 1;

COUNT(DISTINCT) in the outer query is needed in order to remove duplicates by the end_time value.
Perhaps you need to interpret adjacent intervals not as combined, but as separate intervals. I.e. 1-3 and 3-5 are 2 intervals, not one continuous interval. In this case, just adjust the end_time in cte1 by subtracting some small time value from it (less than the time accuracy/granularity).
fiddle

Below is the solution I got from my colleague, and it works. Just post it here for reference.
 select 
       a.id, count(*) as overlapping_shifts
 from dat a
 join dat b
 on a.id = b.id and  
    a.start_time < b.start_time and 
    b.start_time < a.end_time
group by a.id
order by a.id;


The logic to check overlaps is flawed. Also, if this is a clarification then add it to your question, not post it as answer.

@SalmanArshad Thanks for your suggestion. Please feel free to share which part of the logic is flawed. Thank you.

Check (2,3) ,(2,4) - no overlap

Try this：
select distinct(a.id) 
from your_table a
inner join (
   select 
     id, 
     max(start_time) as maxStartTime,
     min(end_time) as minEndTime
   from your_table 
   where start_time < end_time 
   group by id
  ) b on a.id = b.id
where b.maxStartTime < b.minEndTime


Thank you for your proposal. I try to digest your code. Could you please make some edits on the order of query statements? e.g., ...group by id where start_time < end_time may be changed to ...where start_time < end_time group by id) since where should go first, then group by. Thank you again for your efforts.

yes you right,i have edited

This cannot be what you meant.  start_time is always less than end_time, so the first WHERE is pointless.  The inner query produces the largest start and smallest end for this id, which will be replicated for each record.  This does NOTHING to compare the records against one another.  This code either produces ALL records for an id (as in id=1) or NO records (as in id=2).
